# Date picker is not working after deleting the date form input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have used below date picker and facing the issue

https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-datepicker/issues/296

Date picker is not working after deleting the date form input field. Please follow below steps for the issue:

Select the date from picker and check that date will come in input field.
Remove the date from the input field by pressing backspace key.
Now select the date form date picker and set and check that date will not come in date picker.
Please respond as soon as possible......

Comment: Dude you have got to share some code for people to try and help you.

Comment: Provide your code **in the question**, please.

Comment: where have you used angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework???? it's the only javascript issue